# Remove 'undefined' values from JSON in AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a form that submits data to a GoogleSheet as JSON via AJAX.

I want to change it so that blank fields show as just empty rather than showing as `undefined` in the GoogleSheet.

Below is my code:

HTML Form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>MooWoos Stall Booking</title>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel='stylesheet' href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!--build:css css/styles.min.css-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <!--endbuild-->

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light">
        <a class="logo"><img src="assets/logo_opt.png" alt="MooWoos Stall Booking"></a>
    </nav>

    <hr>

    <div class="modal fade" id="redirect_page" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="form-horizontal">

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <div id="user_msg">Booking successful! Redirecting to PayPal... </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 bookingform">
            <h1>Stall Booking Form</h1>
            <p class="lead">
                Fill out the form to book and pay for your stall!
            </p>
            <form id="bookingForm" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
                <!-- BELOW ARE PAYPAL FIELDS FROM PAYPAL GENERATION -->
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                <input type="hidden" id="hosted_button_id" name="hosted_button_id" value="js_value">
                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name </label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" value="" title="Please enter your name" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="address">Address </label>
                    <textarea id="address" name="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Address" title="Please enter your address" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="phone">Telephone Number </label>
                    <input type="tel" id="phone" pattern="(([0]{1})|([\+][4]{2}))([1]|[2]|[3]|[7]){1}\d{9}$" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Telephone Number" value="" title="Please enter the best telephone number to contact you on" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email </label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" value="" title="Please enter your Email address" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    Which date would you like to book?
                    <p></p>
                    <p><input type="radio" name="date" value="13th September" required/> Sunday 13th September</p>
                    <p><input type="radio" name="date" value="6th February" /> Saturday 6th February</p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>What type of stall do you require?</label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="stallType" id="stallType-Preloved" value="Preloved" required>
                        <label for="stallType-Preloved">Preloved</label>
                        <div class="reveal-if-active form-inline">
                            Will you be bringing a clothes rail?
                            <label class="stallLabel" for="c-rail-yes">Yes</label> <input type="radio" id=c-rail-yes name="c-rail" value="Yes" />
                            <label class="stallLabel" for="c-rail-no">No</label> <input type="radio" id=c-rail-no name="c-rail" value="No" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="stallType" id="stallType-Craft" value="Craft">
                        <label for="stallType-Craft">Craft</label>
                        <div class="reveal-if-active">
                            <label for="craftName">What name do you use?</label>
                            <input type="text" id="craftName" name="craftName" class="require-if-active form-control" placeholder="Craft Name" title="Please provide us with your Craft name" value="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="stallType" id="stallType-Business" value="Business">
                        <label for="stallType-Business">Business</label>
                        <div class="reveal-if-active">
                                <label for="bizName">What is your business name?</label>
                                <input type="text" id="bizName" name="bizName" class="require-if-active form-control" placeholder="Business Name" title="Please provide us with your Business name" value="" />
                                <br>
                                Do you have Public Liability Insurance?
                                <label class="insuranceLabel" for="insurance-yes">Yes</label> <input type="radio" id="insurance-yes" name="insurance" class="require-if-active" data-require-pair="#stallType-Business" title="We will require proof of this prior to market day" value="Yes"/>
                                <label class="insuranceLabel" for="insurance-no">No</label> <input type="radio" id="insurance-no" name="insurance" class="require-if-active" data-require-pair="#stallType-Business" title="Our insurance does not cover other businesses. Please ensure you have adequate cover and provide us with proof prior to market day" value="No"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" id="submit-form" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="Book & Pay" />
                    </div>
            </form>
            <p></p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <hr>

    <footer>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <p>Copyright &copy; MooWoos 2018. Booking Form by Luke Brewerton</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </footer>

</div>

<!--build:js js/mwbookings-min.js -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.serialize-object.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

</body>
</html>
```

JS Code:

```
var $form = $('form#bookingForm'),
    url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwaEsXX1iK8nNkkvL57WCYHJCtMAbXlfSpSn3rsJj2spRi-41Y/exec'

function disableAll() {
    $('#c-rail-yes').attr('required', false).attr('disabled', true);
    $('#c-rail-no').attr('required', false).attr('disabled', true);
    $('#craftName').attr('required', false).attr('disabled', true);
    $('#bizName').attr('required', false).attr('disabled', true);
    $('#insurance-yes').attr('required', false).attr('disabled', true);
    $('#insurance-no').attr('required', false).attr('disabled', true);
}

$('#stallType-Preloved').change(function () {
    if(this.checked) {
        disableAll();
        $('#c-rail-yes').attr('required', true).attr('disabled', false);
        $('#c-rail-no').attr('required', true).attr('disabled', false);
        $('#hosted_button_id').attr('value', '7L75UXEHSKFLG');
    }
});

$('#stallType-Craft').change(function () {
    if(this.checked) {
        disableAll();
        $('#craftName').attr('required', true).attr('disabled', false);
        $('#hosted_button_id').attr('value', 'HFTF3KS5T2ETA');
    }
});

$('#stallType-Business').change(function () {
    if(this.checked) {
        disableAll();
        $('#bizName').attr('required', true).attr('disabled', false);
        $('#insurance-yes').attr('required', true).attr('disabled', false);
        $('#insurance-no').attr('required', true).attr('disabled', false);
        $('#hosted_button_id').attr('value', '48R67JG4F7H4J');
    }
});

$('#submit-form').on('click', function(e) {
    var valid = this.form.checkValidity();
    if (valid) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: $form.serializeObject(),
            beforeSend: function (key,value) {
                return (value == undefined) ? "" : value
            },
            success: function () {
                $('#redirect_page').modal('show');
                $('#bookingForm').submit();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I have tried using `beforeSend` but this does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: possibly a bug in the serializeObject plugin function you are using. Does it have `undefined` as some of the values?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no nested objects in your form, you can simply loop on your object elements before sending them

```
let jsObj = $form.serializeObject();

Object.keys(jsObj).forEach(key => {
  jsObj[key] = jsObj[key] ? jsObj[key] : "";
})
```

Then you'll just have to send that object via AJAX :

```
$('#submit-form').on('click', function(e) {
var valid = this.form.checkValidity();
if (valid) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: jsObj,
        beforeSend: function (key,value) {
            return (value == undefined) ? "" : value
        },
        success: function () {
            $('#redirect_page').modal('show');
            $('#bookingForm').submit();
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: This just doesn't submit anything, the AJAX call never seems to submit, the values don't show up in the Sheet and the success or error modal does not show either.

Comment: Weird, this code should not change how AJAX is working, it only changes the object you're sending to your server. Can you provide the logs if any error/warning are appearing?

Comment: I get the following in FF Dev Tools console: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
[Learn More]
main.js:102:17
<anonymous>
http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:102:17
dispatch
http://localhost:3000/js/jquery.min.js:2:41720
add/y.handle
http://localhost:3000/js/jquery.min.js:2:39774

Comment: The AJAX query is still working for me: https://jsfiddle.net/vo518xdb/10/ I replaced (the actual action by a fake one insteadod of the paypal one)

Comment: Hmm, I can't see the values appearing in the GoogleSheet (This is called using the AJAX, the PayPal redirect is the normal submission)

Comment: I see where the problem is comming from, I assumed that form.serializeObject() returns a JSON, when, in actuality, it returns a JS object. I updated my code above.

Comment: That just then submits all the fields as `undefined`